# PHP/JavaScript Facebook Login Redirect loop

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm using the PHP SDK for Facebook to login and the first time it logs in fine but then if you return to the application it get's stuck in a redirect loop.

The flow of the app is as follows, user navigates to an app on facebook page tab, if the do not like the page they see a like us page, if not they get redirected to app.php where the following code exists.

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
require 'sdk/facebook.php';  // Include facebook SDK file
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXX',   // Facebook App ID 
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  // Facebook App Secret
  'cookie' => true,    
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    session_start();
          $fbid = $user_profile['id'];           // To Get Facebook ID

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
   $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
         'next' => 'http:/localhost:8888/logout.php',  // Logout URL full path
        ));
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'        => 'user_birthday', // Permissions to request from the user
        ));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
... html stuff
<?php if ($user): ?>
show the goods
<?php else: ?>
redirect to login     
<script>window.top.location.href = '<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>'; </script>
<?php endif ?>
... rest of html page
```

I've read numerous people having similar issues but yet to find a solid response as to what is happening and why. At this stage none of the JavaScript SDK is being used yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have no idea, what happened, but believe me. When reading your question, I tested your code, did not work, then I tested one of my example app, could not login as well. Couple of minutes after, I tried again your app, I removed function `opcache_reset()` and it **works***.  You really do not have any problem with your code. The reason, you got redirected after successful login, was due to the method `$facebook->getUser()`, which returned always `0` and JS redirect got displayed.

Comment: I got rid of the opcache_rest() and turned it off on the server, I still get caught in a redirect loop, it has to have something to do with the Facebook Cookie and PHP Session

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after you get user data

```
 if(!empty($user)) 
{ 
  if(!$user)
{
  exit();
}
  // YOUR FUNCTION
 }
```